# ListBoxFor type error makes no sense

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting a type error that makes no sense:

> The ViewData item that has the key 'OptionIds' is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<.SelectListItem>'.

It's asking for an int list, but that's not what the method actually calls for. What's going on here?

I've had this happen when the list items, `OptionList` below, is null, but that's not the case this time.

The error occurs on post. The form loads fine, but submission causes the yellow screen of death. I have another model that is identical in all of the parts being used here, and that one works fine. I'm tearing my hair out here.

CSHTML:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.OptionNames, Model.OptionList, new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "true" })
```

Model:

```
public class MyModelEditViewModel
{
    public List<int> OptionIds { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> OptionList { get; set; }
    // Empty constructor for EF
    public MyModelEditViewModel() { }
    // Called from controller with an enumerable from repository
    public MyModelEditViewModel(IEnumerable<SelectListItem> optionList)
    {
        // Not null
        OptionList = optionList;
    }
}
```

---

Edit: Looks like the culprit was [this](https://hastebin.com/wasezolaxe.cs) data annotation attribute that (theoretically) prevents two lists from having overlapping values. When validation failed (no client-side yet), the ViewModel was sent back but `OptionsList` is never posted and therefore never sent back after validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

What *normally* causes that error is setting a `ViewBag` member with the same name as the model property you're binding to (`ViewBag.OptionIds`, in this scenario) with your select list.

That's not occurring in the code you've posted, but I suspect it is in fact in code you neglected to post. Look for anywhere that `ViewBag.OptionIds` (case-insensitive, i.e. `optionIds`, `OPTIONIDS`, etc. are all viewed the same) is being set, and remove that.